# How can I construct a class containing a vector of tuples which can be assigned to constexpr variables?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++23

I was trying to construct a class, which should be constructible at compile time, containing a vector of tuples. I am using c++23. A MWE:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts>
class vector_of_tuple {
public:
   constexpr vector_of_tuple( const std::tuple<Ts...> & value ) : samples( 1, value ) {};
private:
   std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>> samples;
};

constexpr std::tuple<int,long,int> tuple_v = std::make_tuple(1,2,3);
// Below line produce error when compiled with constexpr as shown
constexpr vector_of_tuple<int,long,int> vector_of_tuple_v(tuple_v);
```

The error displayed is that:

> the type ‘const vector_of_tuple<int, long int, int>’ of ‘constexpr’ variable ‘vector_of_tuple_v’ is not literal
> ‘vector_of_tuple<int, long int, int>’ is not literal because:
> non-static data member ‘vector_of_tuple<int, long int, int>::samples’ has non-literal type
> ‘std::vector<std::tuple<int, long int, int>, std::allocator<std::tuple<int, long int, int> > >’ is not literal because:
> **‘std::vector<std::tuple<int, long int, int>, std::allocator<std::tuple<int, long int, int> > >’ does not have ‘constexpr’ destructor**

I expected that this will work as both std::vector and std::tuple are constexpr in c++23, and cppreference says

> A constexpr destructor whose function body is not =delete; must satisfy the following additional requirement:
> every destructor used to destroy non-static data members and base class must be a constexpr destructor.

So how can I construct a class containing a vector of tuples which can be assigned to constexpr variables?

Comment: an object that requires heap allocation cannot be constexpr, however it can be used in a function to create a constexpr object, but the heap allocated object must be deleted by the end of the function.

Comment: in other words you cannot have a constexpr vector, but you can have a constexpr tuple, because tuples don't need heap allocations, the fact that vector has a constexpr destructor simply means it can be created in a function that creates a constexpr object, it doesn't mean you can create a constexpr vector.

Comment: This makes sense - thank you!